# TreeView PopulateOnDemand not working with a custom ImageURL

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I've got a fairly simple treeview where the nodes are PopulateOnDemand and some of the nodes have a custom ImageUrl. When the tree is rendered, attempting to expand one of the nodes with the custom image results in the Javascript error: **orgTree_tvOrgTreet1i' is undefined**.

The line of code that the error is from is a generated script block that looks like

```
TreeView_PopulateNode(orgTree_tvOrgTree_Data,1,orgTree_tvOrgTreen1,orgTree_tvOrgTreet1,orgTree_tvOrgTreet1i,'t','Node Text','2\\10001','f','','tf')
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in the TreeView.

If the node has an ImageURL AND is PopulateOnDemand AND has a SelectAction of None, this bug occurs. Easiest fix is to set the SelectAction to Expand, allowing the user to click the text to expand the tree as well.

I finally found the answer in this forum post from 2006:

http://forums.asp.net/t/995686.aspx